# Why is podman container only reachable with --network=host when started from Jenkins pipeline script?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, podman

I'm using Jenkins to build, deploy and run a podman/docker container.

```
sh 'podman run -d -p 8080:8080 --restart=always host/user/project'
```

Although the build process in Jenkins has been finished, so the container was deployed and is running, the container is not reachable from a web browser, although podman/docker console shows a running container so it actually has to be reachable:

```
$ podman ps
CONTAINER ID  IMAGE                                         COMMAND               CREATED             STATUS                 PORTS                   NAMES
1737f1d56560  host/user/project:latest  /usr/local/s2i/ru...  About a minute ago  Up About a minute ago  0.0.0.0:8080->8080/tcp  pensive_diffie
```

When I execute the same command from above in command line, I get the same result from `docker ps` but this time, the container seems to be reachable from a web browser.
(I'm using the same linux user "jenkins" as Jenkins is doing. Otherwise it would be in a different userspace anyway)

I figured out that I'm able to get it working in Jenkins, when I add --network=host to the command:

```
sh 'podman run -d -p 8080:8080 --network=host --restart=always host/user/project'
```

This is a little bit unsatisfying for me, because I don't know why I need to access the host network when I start the comand from a Jenkins pipeline script. Moreover I cannot run multiple containers (on different ports) when I use --network=host on each container this is started from Jenkins.

Why do I have to use --network=host in Jenkins to access the container via web browser and how can I achieve it to start the container from Jenkins without using --network=host?

Comment: Just a wild guess (without really understanding the topic): Maybe it could be related to Jenkins killing processes https://github.com/containers/podman/issues/15899#issuecomment-1260042007

Comment: @Erik Sjölund I'm not sure if this is really the problem, because if the process would be killed, the container would have been stopped immediately (I had this problem in the past, so I run it as detached mode via -d), but maybe the comments on this page could be helpful. I will try to figure this out.

Comment: @Bevor I am curious if you have some news about this issue as it is occurring to me as well. I found that when you can create and run the container as the "jenkins" user after that Jenkins actually created the container. This is very strange since they are assigned the same port number. It doesn't seem to bother podman that there is already a container listening on that port.
Also, specifying `--network=host` "works" for me as well.

Comment: @speedi33 We redesigned the build process a lil bit because we had to meet other requirements as well. So we use a systemctl script that we restart via Jenkins ```sh "XDG_RUNTIME_DIR=/run/user/`id -u` systemctl --user restart our-app.service"``` and this systemctl script launches the podman container. Here we do not have this problems anymore described in the question.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Okay, that's great. Since for me, it was no problem to switch to non-rootless podman, I simply call podman with `sudo` now. Didn't think of it making that kind of difference.

Answer (score 0):

Try to deactivate temporary SELinux and firewall.